# Is Yondu of Kree origin?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In guardians of the Galaxy 2, Yondu reveals to Rocket that when he was young he was sold to Kree slavers.  However, as far I can recall from the dialogue, it's never explicitly stated that Yondu is a Kree.

From what I can remember, most characters in the Guardians movies that are blue like Yondu have tended to be Kree, including Ronan and the Kree (admiral, captain, whatever) that Nova Prime talked to.

So, is Yondu a Kree?

Answer (score 11):

In [the comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yondu) he was from earth colony Centauri IV and refereed as 
[Centaurian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alien_races_in_Marvel_Comics#C). But in MCU there is no mention of earth's colony on other planet yet.

And from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., Episode 1.15: Yes Men we know Centaurians do exists in MCU

> **Coulson:** "You've visited other realms, seen different species, aliens. Have you ever encountered any that were blue?"
>
> **Sif:**"Yes, of course."
>
> **Coulson:** "Which ones?"
>
> **Sif:**"Uh, Interdites, Levians, Pheragots, Kree, Sarks, Centaurians. The Frost Giants tried to conquer your Earth a
>   millennia ago, but Asgard drove them away."
>
> **Coulson:** "Oh. Well, thanks for that."
>
> [- marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Sif/Quote)

It is not exactly mentioned in the film itself but it's safe to assume he is Centaurian not Kree.

Comment: Centauri IV was colonized in the 29th century in the comics, while the GotG movies take place in 2014. It's safe to say that it's not an Earth colony in this version, barring a possible super-advanced past earth culture.